# Kivy freezing when when downloading video

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, pytube

I want to make an app that downloads youtube videos with pytube and kivy. The problem is that the app freezes and then stops responding when the download starts. I know it starts to download because it creates a mp4 file. I looked into scheduling and multithreading but I don't know how those work and I'm not even sure they are a solution to my problem in the first place. Anyone that can tell me where to look?

the python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from pytube import YouTube

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def download_video(self, link):
         yt = YouTube(link)
         yt.streams.first().download()

class Youtube(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
 Youtube().run()
```

the kivy file:

```
 MyWidget:

 <MyWidget>:

 BoxLayout:
     orientation: 'horizontal'
     Button:
        text: 'press to download'
        on_press: root.download_video(url.text)
     TextInput:
        text: 'paste the youtube URL here'
        id: url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recently intimidated by threading myself, talk about GIL. The threading library itself isn't too complicated however and this problem is a great use-case for it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from pytube import YouTube

# import Thread from threading
from threading import Thread

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

     # Create a start_download method
    def start_download(self):
        # Creates a new thread that calls the download_video method
        download = Thread(target=self.download_video)

        # Starts the new thread
        download.start()

    def download_video(self):
         # I implemented the text grabbing here because I came across a weird error if I passed it from the button (something about 44 errors?) 
         yt = YouTube(self.ids.url.text)
         yt.streams.first().download()

class Youtube(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Youtube().run()
```

youtube.kv

```
<MyWidget>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Button:
        text: 'press to download'
        # Call the start download method to create a new thread rather than override the current.
        on_press: root.start_download()
    TextInput:
        text: 'paste the youtube URL here'
        id: url
```

1) You enter the url

2) You click download button

3) This triggers a start_download method.

4) The start_download creates a thread that runs your download method that takes the url.text *at the current time* as an argument. This means you can enter additional urls, while that is downloading without overwriting the url text in the previous calls because they're in different threads of execution.

[Video Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXonWs6VVkI&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I'll definitely look into threading more.